# C# - Keyboard Hook + Turn Basic Latin into Wide Characters

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm currently trying to hook the keyboard, and turn the basic latin input (0x21 < && 0x7e >) into the wide characters (0xff10 < && 0xff6d >) input.

In short description, whenever user press for ex. "A" key on their keyboard, the input should be turned into the "Ａ" (so called a e s t h e t i c). Wide Characters are Unicode. I have no single problem, turning A into B. The problem starts when it comes to displaying the Unicode.

I'm using http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ library. So far my code is:

```
private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if(nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)257)
    {
        int _vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        if(_vkCode >= 0x21 && _vkCode <= 0x7e)
        {
            _vkCode += 0xfee0;
            InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(_vkCode)));
            return (IntPtr)1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

but all I get out of it, is just a question mark.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem. I've found a way around. All you've to do, is generate the character -> hook the keyboard copy -> hook the keyboard paste.

```
public bool _vaporize = false;
private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if(_vaporize)
        return (IntPtr)1;
    if(nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)257 || wParam == (IntPtr)256)
    {
        int _vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
        if(_vkCode >= 0x21 && _vkCode <= 0x7e)
        {
            if(wParam == (IntPtr)257)
                return (IntPtr)1;
            Clipboard.SetText(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(_vkCode + 0xfee0)));
            _vaporize = true;
            SendKeys.Send("^(v)");
            _vaporize = false;
            return (IntPtr)1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Although, my solution won't work on Windows newer than 8.1.